# Модуль logging. Трассировка не записывается в log

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, логирование

Использую модуль *logging* для записи отладочной информации в лог-файл.

Создаю ошибку в строке **`26`**.

```
from sys import argv, exit
import logging
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, a0):
        #a = 5 / 0
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_format = '%(asctime)s %(filename)s: %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename="tst_logfile.log", format=log_format,
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level='DEBUG')
    try:
        app = QApplication(argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        # create an error
        a = 5 / 0

    except Exception as e:
        logging.debug(e, exc_info=True)

    exit(app.exec_())
```

Всё работает отлично, лог записывается. 
Причем приложение продолжает работать (**а должно вылетать**).

```
2022-05-28 17:32:27 tst.py: division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\tst.py", line 26, in <module>
    a = 5 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Но стоит перенести ошибку в событие `mousePressEvent` (строка 14), трассировка в файл не записывается. Хотя ошибка возникает и приложение прекращает работу.

```
from sys import argv, exit
import logging
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, a0):
        a = 5 / 0
        #pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_format = '%(asctime)s %(filename)s: %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename="tst_logfile.log", format=log_format,
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level='DEBUG')
    try:
        app = QApplication(argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        # create an error
        #a = 5 / 0

    except Exception as e:
        logging.debug(e, exc_info=True)

    exit(app.exec_())
```

Что я делаю неправильно? 
Как сделать, чтобы все ошибки приложения записывались в лог?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Всё работает отлично, лог записывается.
> Причем приложение продолжает работать (а должно вылетать).

Нет, не должно вылетать,
так как вы обернули ошибку в **`try - except`**.

> Но стоит перенести ошибку в событие `mousePressEvent`,
> трассировка в файл не записывается.
> Хотя ошибка возникает и приложение прекращает работу.

[**traceback**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) — Print or retrieve a stack traceback, вам в помощь.

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback                                                       # !!! +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 300)
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        name = 'Павел'
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<h1>Привет, {name}!</h1>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D98C00;')
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)        

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        a = 77 // 0                                                          # !!!

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
def except_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    tb = "".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb))        
    logging.error(f'\n Что-то пошло не так - Error: {tb}\n') 
    msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(
        None, 
        'Внимание', 
        f'{tb}'
    )
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_format = '%(asctime)s %(filename)s: %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename="tst_logfile.log", format=log_format,
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level='DEBUG')
# +++                        
    sys.excepthook = except_hook                                           # +++
    
    try:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.show()
        # create an error
        a = 5 / 0
    except Exception as e:
        logging.debug(e, exc_info=True)
        
        logging.error(f'\nЧто-то пошло не так - Error: {e}\n')
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(
            None, 
            'Внимание', 
            f'Что-то пошло не так - Error: \n{e}'
        )   
        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Comment: @Павел пожалуйста.